# Highcharts Spider Chart with different scale for each category

Tags: charts, highcharts, web-crawler, categories, scale

Using highcharts v11.2.0 and highcharts-react-official v3.2.1. Have created a Spider Chart with 7 categories however each category will require a different scale to be meaningful. I cannot figure out how to do this. Is this even possible? The Highcharts examples are overly simplistic.

I have tried adding additional objects to the yAxis array and while these do display correctly the values do not correlate with the labels.
For example:

```
{
  gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
  lineWidth:0,
  max: 170,
  min: 80,
  tickAmount: 5,
  angle: 26,
  labels: {
    style: {color: '#b0b0b0'}
  }
}
```

When I pass a value of say 165 if appears on the radial of the chart as maybe half way instead of close to the outer edge.

So I have achieved this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8rIN.png)

Which looks great but the values don't match the scale.

Comment: Hi, it looks like following topic might be what you're searching for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759474/spiderweb-highcharts-with-multiple-scales-on-multiple-axes